# Flutter DropdownButtonFormField same value error

Tags: flutter, dropdown, dropdownbutton, flutter-dropdownbutton

I have two DropdownButtonFormfield on my page. They have relation. The second is filling after select an item from first. I am facing an error on this situation: Select an item from first, select an item from second, change the first value. I am seeing this error after apply this steps.

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButtonFormField]'s value: 1789. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
dropdown.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 933 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

My code :

```
DropdownButtonFormField<int?>(
        value: userController
         .selectedReturnCity,
        items: List.generate(
                  userController.storeCityFilter?.length ?? 0,
                   (index) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                         value: userController.storeCityFilter![index]['id'],
                                         child: Text(userController
                                                      .storeCityFilter![index]['value']))),
        onChanged: (value) async {
                      userController.selectedReturnCity = value == 0 ? null : value;
                      //Get data for second dropdown, the function is clears the data used by the second dropdown
                      await userController.getStores(city: userController.selectedReturnCity,
                                                  type: "market");
                  },
           ),
           10.v(),
DropdownButtonFormField<int?>(
        value: userController.selectedReturnStore,
        items: List.generate(
                  userController.storeList?.length ?? 0,
                   (index) => DropdownMenuItem<int?>(
                                         value: userController.storeList?[index].id,
                                         child: Text(userController.storeList?[index].name ?? ''))),
onChanged: (value) {userController.selectedReturnStore = value;
},
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This situation happens when you try to set `value: userController.selectedReturnCity` and the value of `userController.selectedReturnCity` doesn't exist in your list or
there are two or more same items/objects in your list and try to set that value in  `userController.selectedReturnCity`.

Because the `value` property of `DropdownButtonFormField` means which item will be selected in your dropdown. Please debug both of your dropdowns.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My error on second Dropdown and selectedReturnStore. I am updating null to selectedReturnStore on userController.getStores func's first line.

Comment: Your answer not working for me. The error keep shows.

Comment: So when you're selecting the first dropdown for the second time, you got this error on the second dropdown, right?

Comment: Yes, right. My second dropdown give error after update first value.

Comment: It's all about the data you're providing in the list and what you're setting value property.  You have to give a proper explanation with your provided data.  Based on your error I can mention one thing which is you're setting the value with id 1789 which is not present in your list.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with selectedReturnStore set to 0. I can't explain to myself :D bullshit..